# SVG seems to have margin(?) at bottom of it, can't remove it

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="navbarContentHamburger">
     <svg width="25" height="25">
          <path d="M0,5 50,5" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="3"/>
          <path d="M0,10 50,10" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="3"/>
          <path d="M0,15 50,15" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="3"/>
     </svg>
</div>
```

This is the code I use to make my hamburger menu. I pair it next to my "Menu" header tag and if I inspect element on my SVG, it seems it has a margin of around 2-3px underneath it, pushing my navbar down.

Tried adding an !important tag to margin-bottom:0; but that does not seem to work.

Comment: Do you have an example website? Because this code seems to be good

Comment: actually yes, I should have linked 
 it.https://donnieberry97.github.io/project2/

Answer (score 2):

Your svg actually does not have margin, so thats not part of the problem.
Try adding `display: block;` to the svg element itself. Alternatively setting its height to just 21 should fix that issue also, as your svg currently is higher than needed.